# iOS Simulator does not display the keyboard on google sign in

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, swift5

I am working with Google sign in to log in to the app, this works perfectly on the device, but on Simulator:

- the physical keyboard is not working
- the software keyboard is not appearing
- copy and paste does not work
- any command like "Cmnd" + "Q" is not working

This happens ONLY when the app has a google sign in on. Any other application in simulator everything else is working. 
This situation happens even if I am not debugging the app, and I just open the app in the simulator.

*Current situation:*

- iOS 13.3 simulator
- xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)
- google sign in SDK version 5.0.2 with CocoaPods
- I have integrated the SDK in a full SwiftUI application

*What I have tried so far:*

- erase the device from the "Simulator.app" menu
- delete the app and reinstall
- clean all derived data
- delete the ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iphonesimulator.plist

The problem was not existing with the version 4.4.0 of the SignIn SDK from google

*Workaround*
If I go out of the app toggle the keyboard (Hardware -> Keyboard -> Toggle software keyboard) the software keyboard does appear, the physical keyboard is still not working and the even copy and paste are not appearing

[the keyboard is working elsewhere](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaREr.png)

[Not working in google "Sign In"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkPcf.png)

Comment: When you have "connect hardware keyboard" the keyboard will not appear as on an actual device the onscreen keyboard doesn't appear when a Bluetooth/external keyboard is connected.

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited the question, the physical keyboard does not work in it, it works in any other place. No Bluetooth or external keyboard are connected. I am on a Macbook pro with Mac OS Catalina 10.15.3 (19D76)

Comment: Disable the "Connect Hardware Keyboard" option so the simulated device does not believe a hardware keyboard is connected.